# How do I make AutoHotKey on my host OS still work even when I have my VMware virtual machine in fullscreen or focused?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I have numerous shortcut keys defined in my AutoHotKey script. I'm completely crippled without them.

They normally work, but whenever I have focused my VMware virtual machine, or when I'm "immersed" in it in fullscreen, the shortcut keys don't work. As understandable as this may be, since the VM has now "taken over" the keyboard, I still wish for this to happen since some of the shortcut keys control things like "mute sounds globally" or "play next track".

It is not an option to install AutoHotKey inside the VM and use the same script there, even though it would work. I want this to work regardless of what I'm doing; the VMware VM is just an example of when it really causes problems for me.

Is it possible at all? Maybe even easily?

Comment: I have the same problem (although it's not so much a problem because it's *expected* behaviour) but I just press the Host key (right ctrl on Virtualbox, probably ctrl + alt on VMware) and then the combination works through the host instead. Funnily enough after I do it I have to press Host again if I want to use the shortcut again, even if I have not moved mouse or typed in the guest machine (Virtualbox seems to grab the keystrokes if the window is in focus, which I rely on more than I rely on my shortcuts).

Comment: I suppose you usually start VMware after starting AutoHotKey. In Windows, the last key-hook has the priority, so VMware gets the keys before AutoHotKey. Try to exit and restart AutoHotKey  after VMware is already running, to establish its key-hook as having the priority. If this succeeds, the hotkeys will execute on the host.

Comment: @harrymc hello I had the same idea, but even when I run the VM and I run the AHK script hereafter, the virtual machine still grabs the input. I even restarted the AHK script multiple times, it still doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

To execute some AutoHotkey script while a VM has the focus/grabbed input, run the AutoHotkey script from some other trigger and not from key input.

For example, muting the system volume and changing its volume is very handy and I do that with an Elgato Stream Deck keypad that has an AutoHotkey script given to the "System > Open" function to run some scripts. These are run-and-exit scripts as they do not specify hotkeys.

The audio control built into the Stream Deck will let you mute/unmute. I use the info from the script talked about here: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?style=1&t=70346 to get the audio output device index I want, then write an AHK script with the one line SoundSet command to do something to the sound.

I now have these four buttons in a row on my Stream Deck:

```
1. Toggle-Mute         Built-In Stream Deck function
2. Volume-Down-5%      SoundSet, -5, MASTER, VOLUME, 12
3. Volume-50%          SoundSet, 50, MASTER, VOLUME, 12
4. Volume-Up-5%        SoundSet, +5, MASTER, VOLUME, 12
5. Volume-100          SoundSet, 100, MASTER, VOLUME, 12
```

(12 is the index of the audio for my main speakers. This index sometimes changes when the OS upgrades and/or other audio devices are installed.)

Not sure how other HID devices work with the VM having focus, but the Stream Deck works great with AutoHotkey scripts, and the only issue would be if you need to press keys, as those would go into the VM and not the host.